# Sequential testing

Tags: r, t-test

I have been exposed to R before but after being away from the language for 10 years I find my self having to start from the start.

I have a large data set with over 1 million rows and 20 variables. I know there are quicker and faster ways of mining that data but my customer insists on using hypothesis testing to identify significant segments/clusters. I am looking for some R code that would be able to perform a sequential t-test across each of the 20 variables one at a time. Only returning significant variables and samples in table format.

Would really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 4):

Here is some quick and dirty code for carrying out multiple t-tests over a fake dataset. There may be more elegant way of doing this, but that should let you started with R in a simple way. This solution *assumes* that the 20 samples are independent.

```
# Simulate some data
dfrm <- replicate(20, rnorm(1e6))
colnames(dfrm) <- paste("V", 1:20, sep="")

# Add random signal 
inc <- sample(1:20, 3)
dfrm[,inc] <- dfrm[,inc]+.5

# Setup testing framework (each combination of variables)
idx <- combn(20, 2)
pval <- numeric(ncol(idx))
for (i in 1:ncol(idx))
  pval[i] <- t.test(dfrm[,idx[1,i]], dfrm[,idx[2,i]])$p.value

# No. significant test at 5%
sum(pval<.05)

# All variables that were found associated
colnames(dfrm)[unique(as.vector(idx[,pval<.05]))]

# Pretty print as table (well, a data.frame; but it can be exported 
# as LaTeX with the xtable package.)
res <- data.frame(t(idx[,pval<.05]), p=pval[pval<.05])
res$X1 <- colnames(dfrm)[res$X1]
res$X2 <- colnames(dfrm)[res$X2]

# After Bonferroni correction
res$padj <- p.adjust(res$p, method="bonf")
res[res$padj<.05,]
```

I only reported variable names and associated p-values (with and without correction for multiple tests), but you can add extra information in the `for` loop (e.g., $t$ value, dof, etc.). Please note that R uses Welch's t-test as the default. See `help(t.test)` to use classical Student t-test instead. Sample results look like

```
> res
   X1  X2           p      padj
1  V1  V4 0.000000000 0.0000000
2  V1  V5 0.000000000 0.0000000
3  V1  V7 0.000000000 0.0000000
4  V2  V4 0.000000000 0.0000000
5  V2  V5 0.000000000 0.0000000
6  V2  V7 0.000000000 0.0000000
7  V3  V4 0.000000000 0.0000000
8  V3  V5 0.000000000 0.0000000
9  V3  V6 0.009132565 0.5296888
10 V3  V7 0.000000000 0.0000000
11 V3  V9 0.014075639 0.8163871
```

If all variables are numerical, and data were collected on the same sample, you need a paired t-test (`paired=TRUE`) but why not using simple correlation tests directly? (Simply replace `t.test()` with `cor.test()` in the testing loop.)

Comment: I would suggest using q-values to control for false discoveries rather than bonferroni corrections.

Comment: @martino Fair enough. Step-down methods would also be less conservative than Bonferroni adjustment. The reason I gave the latter is that if the customer "insists on using hypothesis testing to identify significant segments/clusters" I would not expect he is looking for complex adjustment to mass bivariate screening of candidate predictors; hence my suggestion for a 'simple' method of correction for multiple comparisons, if any should be given.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `expand.grid` to construct pairwise combinations and run a loop on all pairs, performing your test. It would be fairly easy to filter out "significant" results.

```
> expand.grid(letters[1:5], letters[1:5]) #you would actually insert column/variable names
   Var1 Var2
1     a    a
2     b    a
3     c    a
4     d    a
5     e    a
6     a    b
7     b    b
8     c    b
9     d    b
10    e    b
11    a    c
12    b    c
13    c    c
14    d    c
15    e    c
16    a    d
17    b    d
18    c    d
19    d    d
20    e    d
21    a    e
22    b    e
23    c    e
24    d    e
25    e    e
```

Here's a simple way to obtain non-repeated cases and duplicates. Thanks to [@Joris](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9413457/count-the-number-of-valid-observations-no-na-in-any-combination-of-variables) for reminding me of the function.

```
> t(combn(letters[1:5], 2))
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,] "a"  "b" 
 [2,] "a"  "c" 
 [3,] "a"  "d" 
 [4,] "a"  "e" 
 [5,] "b"  "c" 
 [6,] "b"  "d" 
 [7,] "b"  "e" 
 [8,] "c"  "d" 
 [9,] "c"  "e" 
[10,] "d"  "e"
```

Comment: With `expand.grid()` you're testing the same pairs of variables twice as well as each variable with itself; so you will need to filter out the result.

Comment: Yes, of course, thanks for pointing out the "setback".